# Getting error add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id' in django

Tags: python, django

when i run the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/crud/add/1` it gives me error `add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'`, can anyone please help me why i am getting this error ?  here i have added my whole code, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ?

urls.py

```
app_name = 'crud'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    path('add/',views.add, name='add'),
    path('add/<int:id>',views.add, name='update'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.


from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from .models import Pages
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render



def index(request):
    pagelist = Pages.objects.all()
    context = {'pagelist': pagelist}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def add(request):
    if request.POST:
        title = request.POST.get("title")
        permialink = request.POST.get("permialink")
        updated_date = request.POST.get("updated_date")
        bodytext = request.POST.get("bodytext")

        page_data = Pages(title=title,permialink=permialink,updated_date=updated_date,bodytext=bodytext)
        page_data.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('crud:index', args=('')))
    else:
        return render(request,'polls/add.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing parameter in URL but not receiving it in in view function. You should define add function like this

```
def add(request, id=None):
    pass
    # rest of code
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a method, eg:

```
@app.route('/transcript/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def transcript(employeeId):
  if x == 'NoneType': 
        employee = Employee()        
    else:
        employee = Employee(employeeId)
```

The argument doesn't match the route, eg `employeeId` doesn't equal **<int:id>**, so we change the argument to `id`

```
@app.route('/transcript/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def transcript(id):
  if x == 'NoneType': 
        employee = Employee()        
    else:
        employee = Employee(employeeId)
```

Strangely we still get the same error. The trick is that you may *not* have changed all old occurrences of the old `employeeId` argument:

```
@app.route('/transcript/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def transcript(id):
  if x == 'NoneType': 
        employee = Employee()        
    else:
        employee = Employee(id)
```